# No $p$-torsion in $\pi_{2p+1}(S^3)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

For a prime $p$, it is well-known that the first $p$-torsion in $\pi_i(S^3)$ appears at $i=2p$.

Naturally, one is curious about the next homotopy group:

> Is there any $p$-torsion in $\pi_{2p+1}(S^3)$?

The answer for $p=2$ is trivially positive since $\pi_5(S^3)=\pi_4(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

So let's suppose $p$ is an odd prime.
By looking at the list of $\pi_i(S^3)$, I get the impression:

> $\pi_{2p+1}(S^3)$ has no $p$-torsion.

Is this true? I failed to think of anything helpful.

If this is true, how can we prove it? I have no idea to start...

Generally, let the second $p$-torsion appear at $i=k$, then:

> How big and how small can $k-2p$ be?

Is there any estimate of this number $k-2p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\Lambda$-algebra should be some help. (This was originally defined in the "[6-author paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938366900243)", with a corrected version due to [Bousfield and Kan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938372900249). See also [Computing the Homology of the Lambda Algebra](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-58-337/) by Tangora.) It is an algebra $\Lambda$ which forms the $E_1$-term of the Adams spectral sequence converging to the stable homotopy groups of spheres, together with subalgebras $\Lambda(n)$ which, at least for $n$ odd, form the $E_1$-term of the unstable Adams spectral sequence converging to the homotopy groups of $S^n$.

$\Lambda$ is a quotient of a free noncommutative algebra on generators $\mu_i$, $i \geq 0$, and $\lambda_i$, $i > 0$, with

- $\deg \mu_i = 2i(p-1)$,
- $\deg \lambda_i = 2i(p-1)-1$.

The degree $j$ part of $\Lambda$ or of $\Lambda(n)$ corresponds to $\pi_{n+j}(S^{n})$. The first few of the generators are $\mu_0$ in degree $0$, $\lambda_1$ in degree $2p-3$, $\mu_1$ in degree $2p-2$, $\lambda_2$ in degree $4p-5$, etc. The element $\mu_1$ in degree $2p-2$ supports a differential and hence doesn't contribute to $\pi_{n+2p-2}(S^n)$. (I haven't checked the details for this, and it should be checked.) So the first potential $p$-torsion would be in $\pi_{n+2p-3}(S^n)$. After that, $\Lambda$ has no elements in degrees between $2p-1$ and $4p-7$, so the next possible $p$-torsion would come from $\lambda_1^2$ in $\pi_{n+4p-6}$, as well terms like $\lambda_1^2 \mu_1^j$, etc., all in the same degree.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and sorry for my super late reply. I'm only familiar with Serre spectral sequences, so I was expecting an answer using slightly more "elementary" tools. I'll accept your answer because it makes sense to me anyway and no one else has answered.

Comment: I'll turn back to work through your idea once I get acquainted with Adams spectral sequences. :)

Comment: It is hard to compute homotopy groups, and it's an interesting question to see how far you can get just with the Serre SS, but the Adams SS and related tools tend to be more effective.